# Aspect ratio of html element (inside img tag)

Tags: css, image, html

Why is this happening? And how to fix? In my opinion, IE and Opera works fine in all cases, but not so good in other browsers for "height".

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="data" src="http://www.jpeg.org//images/blue_large_05.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS (height):

```
.image {
    overflow: hidden;        
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: intrinsic;
    display: inline-block;

    height: 100px; //Is buggy
}

.data {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

CSS (width):

```
.image {
    overflow: hidden;        
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: intrinsic;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 200px;
}

.data {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Property values *intrinsic* && *-moz-max-content* for correct width in *display:block*.

Comment: Never heard of `intrinsic`, something new for me

Comment: Why is what happening? How to fix what?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything unexpected about what it's doing.  When you set .img height to 100%, it makes it 100% of the *parent element's height*. In this case that's going to distort the image.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should put height: **auto**; for the image. Then the browsers will calculate correct height and image will be in the correct ratio.